# What is the formula to convert the seconds to hours and minutes

Tags: c++

I have tried multiple times but still fail. The hours converted is correct but it will has additional 2 seconds for any input given.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
private:
    int T1, T2, T3;

public:
    void getseconds(void);
    void getinhours(void);
};

void Time::getseconds(void)
{
    cout << "Enter time-1 in seconds: ";
    cin >> T1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter time-2 in seconds: ";
    cin >> T2;
    cout << endl;
}

void Time::getinhours(void)
{
    T3 = (T1 + T2) / 3600;
    cout << "The Time is: " << T3 /*hours*/ << " : " << (T3 % 3600) / 60 /*seconds*/ << " : " <<  T3 % 60 /*minutes*/;
    cout << endl;

}

int main()
{
    Time t;
    t.getseconds();
    t.getinhours();
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: If you divide by 3600, you can't magically get the minutes and seconds back later...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: A minute has 60 seconds and an hour has 60 minutes, what's actually unclear about that?

Comment: You should probably read [this excellent article by Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on how to debug small programs, such as your own, and apply the techniques described there.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is dividing at the wrong time and place:

```
T3 = T1 + T2;
cout << "The Time is: " << T3 / 3600 /*hours*/ << " : " ;
cout <<  (T3 / 60) % 60 /*minutes*/ << " : ";
cout << T3 % 60 /*seconds*/ << endl;
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks for your cooperation :)

Comment: @A'inAmran glad this helped :))) if so please accept my answer as correct :)